# WriteStartDocument() throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmltextwriter

I'm trying to generate XML and I encounter this exception:

```
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);

xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("userInfo");
```

It gives me an exception:

`WriteStartDocument needs to be the first call.`

But as you can see, I did call the WriteStartDocument() first!

Any ideas?

Comment: You have something wierd going on there? I've just tried the code exactly as you have it and it works fine, even if I write something to Response before hand.

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working. I just tried it on a new project and it works well. Just not in my VPC environment.

Comment: This is very strange, it now works without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

However there are already other things in the Response stream (e.g. HTTP headers).

Probably better to write XML to a StringWriter and then write the string to Response.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(false);
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("userInfo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to clear your aspx file of content so that only the Page directive is left, i.e.:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

Also use Response.Output instead of Response.OutputStream:

```
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(Response.Output); 
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(); 
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("userInfo");
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: still the same thing. I have this code in the Page_Load, would this affect it ?